# Como criar Checkbox dinâmicamente com windows forms?

Tags: c#, winforms

Tenho um lista que retorna do Banco de Dados e para cada registro preciso criar um `checkbox` de **forma dinâmica**, fiz uma pesquisa e encontrei alguns exemplos para **WebForms** e preciso de exemplo para **Windows Forms**

Seria algo assim, Exemplo:

```
private void CriarCheckboxDinamicamente()
        {
            try
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
                {
                    this.SuspendLayout();
                    var chk = new System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox();
                    chk.Name = "Motivo" + i.ToString();
                    chk.Text = "Motivo" + i.ToString();
                    pnlModalMotivo.Controls.Add(chk);
                    this.ResumeLayout(false);
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Erro: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

O problema era que os controles estavam sendo criados sobrepostos uns aos outros, faltava definir o `Location` e ficou assim:

```
private void btnAdicionar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                int pontoX = 77;
                int pontoY = 86;
                for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
                {
                    this.SuspendLayout();
                    var chk = new System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox();
                    chk.Location = new Point(pontoY, pontoX);
                    chk.Name = "chk" + i.ToString();
                    chk.Text = "Motivo" + i.ToString();
                    pnlModalMotivo.Controls.Add(chk);
                    this.ResumeLayout(false);
                    pontoX = pontoX + 50;
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Erro: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Você também poderia utilizar um FlowLayoutPanel por exemplo